# failed composer update with a dependency on a non existstent service

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When I do :

```
composer update
```

I have this :

> The service "fos_user.email_update_listener" has a dependency on a non-exis
>         tent service "fos_user.email_update_confirmation".

Answer (score 1):

Its a bugs on version dev-master for :

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "dev-master"
```

see more here.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2662

Answer (score 0):

Check your yaml/neon config file, the problem is with DI configuration

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by enabled the confirmation mail into the registration...

> registration: enabled: true

Comment: Is this a command that you ran via bin/console or a yaml file change? can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this is add the following to your **app/config/config.yml** file:

```
fos_user:
    ...
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
```

I tested on a Symfony 3.2.13 and this resolves the issue.

It is documented here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html